# Couchbase clarification

Tags: couchbase

I am running into a problem using couchbase, but it may be because I don't quite understand how couchbase works. I have created a simple console .NET app to do some simple stores and gets on data. The problem I am having is when I close the app, then restart it and try to get data I previously stored, it will not retrieve any data. But, if I store and then get before closing the app, it returns data. Can anyone offer me clarification? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found my problem... I was not disposing of the client properly. I had the client as a member of another class, which is what I had in my using statement, so I guess that does not properly dispose.

Comment: Disposing shouldn't have caused this behavior.  Could you post your code here or at http://www.couchbase.com/forums/sdks/sdks?